# SQL Many to Many Filter only for Specific Combination of Data

Tags: sql

I've a many to many mapping table with the following data.

```
ID       Person             Role
-----------------------------------------------------
1          P1                R1
2          P1                R2
3          P1                R3
4          P2                R1
5          P2                R3
6          P2                R5
7          P3                R3
8          P4                R1
9          P4                R2
10         P4                R3
11         P4                R4
12         P4                R5
13         P5                R1
14         P5                R2
15         P5                R3
```

I would like to filter only the persons with Roles R1,R2,R3. The correct person with the only roles R1, R2, R3 are P1 and P5.

The following query returns also the person with roles R1,R2,R3,R4 too.

```
 SELECT PERSON 
   FROM RMS.PERSONROLE
  WHERE role IN ('R1', 'R2','R3') 
  GROUP   
     BY PERSON HAVING COUNT(ROLE)=3;

Expected Output
----------------------
Person
----------------------         
P1
P5
```

Comment: For future reference you shouldn't spam DBMS tags. Only put the one that you are actually working with, because the solution can vary.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  Person
from    Table1
group by
        Person
having  group_concat(role order by role) = 'R1,R2,R3'
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0f2dd/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

Something to think about...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(person INT NOT NULL
,role INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(person,role)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,101),
(1,102),
(1,103),
(2,101),
(2,103),
(2,105),
(3,103),
(4,101),
(4,102),
(4,103),
(4,104),
(4,105),
(5,101),
(5,102),
(5,103);

SELECT person
     , COUNT(*)x
     , SUM(role IN(101,102,103))y 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY person;
+--------+---+------+
| person | x | y    |
+--------+---+------+
|      1 | 3 |    3 |
|      2 | 3 |    2 |
|      3 | 1 |    1 |
|      4 | 5 |    3 |
|      5 | 3 |    3 |
+--------+---+------+
```

Comment: +10. with a guarantee of non-NULL values and uniqueness of the (person,role) tuple... shweeeet.

Comment: This query will list persons in R1, R2 and R3, but it doesn't demand that they are only in those groups

Comment: @andomar - which is why it's something to think about ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `(person,role)` tuple is unique in the table, we could do something like this:

```
 SELECT p.PERSON 
   FROM RMS.PERSONROLE p
  GROUP   
     BY p.PERSON
 HAVING 3 = SUM(IF(p.role IN ('R1','R2','R3'),1,0)
    AND 3 = SUM(1)
```

Without a guarantee of uniqueness, we can tweak it a bit to get count of distinct role values

```
 SELECT p.PERSON 
   FROM RMS.PERSONROLE p
  GROUP   
     BY p.PERSON
 HAVING 3 = COUNT(DISTINCT IF(p.role IN ('R1','R2','R3'),p.role,NULL))
    AND 3 = COUNT(DISTINCT p.role)
```

**EDIT**

The answer above is for MySQL. A more portable ANSI-standards compliant version, replace the MySQL `IF()` function with a suitable `CASE` expression.

```
 SELECT p.PERSON 
   FROM RMS.PERSONROLE p
  GROUP   
     BY p.PERSON
 HAVING 3 = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN p.role IN ('R1','R2','R3') THEN p.role END)
    AND 3 = COUNT(DISTINCT p.role)
```

Comment: You are the first person I've ever seen that adds a new line to GROUP BY to keep the right justification clean like me. Good on you.

Comment: @Error_2646: I don't understand why *everybody* doesn't do it that way. (My best guess is that they're expecting to never have to read the SQL after they write it. Or maybe they are just way smarter than me.)

Answer (score 0):

This query should work:

```
SELECT PERSON 
FROM PERSONROLE
WHERE PERSON NOT IN 
(
    SELECT PERSON FROM PERSONROLE WHERE role NOT IN('R1', 'R2','R3')
)  
GROUP BY PERSON HAVING COUNT(ROLE)=3;
```

Or this might be nicer

```
SELECT p.PERSON FROM PERSONROLE p 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT PERSON FROM PERSONROLE WHERE role NOT IN('R1', 'R2','R3')
) a on  p.PERSON = a.person
WHERE a.person is null
GROUP BY PERSON HAVING COUNT(ROLE)=3;
```

Comment: this is an ugly way to do it.

Comment: i fail to see any advantage of an extra (and unnecessary) SELECT. either as a subquery or an inline view.  Be very careful with the `NOT IN (subquery)` pattern, be aware of what happens when a NULL value is returned by the subquery. (OP didn't provide any *guarantee* that the `person` column won't ever be NULL,) In terms of MySQL performance, I expect an execution plan that does one pass through the table, without a subquery and without materializing a derived table, will be more efficient.

Comment: I might have used an appropriate synonym for ugly (*adj*) *synonyms*  unattractive, unappealing, ...

Answer (score 0):

I just exclude the `roles` that you don't want :

```
SELECT P.PERSON 
FROM RMS.PERSONROLE P
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM RMS.PERSONROLE 
                   WHERE Person = P.Person AND role IN ('R4', 'R5')
                  );
```

However, this might be not give the desired result that you want. So, i would go with `GROUP BY` Clause

```
SELECT PERSON 
FROM RMS.PERSONROLE
WHERE role IN ('R1', 'R2','R3') 
GROUP BY PERSON 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ROLE) = 3;
```

Comment: Neither query will list persons that are in, and only in, R1, R2 and R3